# Files still showing after calling QFileSystem::setNameFilters

Tags: qt, listview, filter, qfilesystemmodel

I just make a simple example about showing files/directories using QFileSystemModel and QListView. It works fine. And I want to filter some types of files I define.

```
QStringList list;
list << "*.jpg" << ".png";
model.setNameFilters(list);
```

the files I dont want to show up,such as test.doc, still in the listview, but they can not be selected. It is not what I want. I want it hidden. How to?

thanks.

Comment: Just call model.setNameFilterDisables(false) to do the work.

Comment: So is this now answered?

Answer (score -1):

```
model.setNameFilterDisables(false);
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation.